# JavaScript Destructure and assign to new object

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

In JavaScript/Typescript,

What is the short version to destructure and then assign in a new object like so :

```
const payload: MyPayload = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }

// Destruct
const { a, c, e } = payload;

// New Obj
const newPayload = {
  a, c, e
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with the object and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for a new object.

```js
const
    getParts = ({ a, c, e }) => ({ a, c, e }),
    payload = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
    parts = getParts(payload);

console.log(parts);
```

Comment: I guess this won't compile if any of these props are optional in `MyPayload`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use IIFE

```js
const payload = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }

const obj = (({a,c,e}) => ({a,c,e}))(payload)

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the object during destructuring using [object rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring):

```js
const payload = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }

const { b, d, ...newPayload } = payload

console.log(newPayload)
```

Comment: This only works if you know all the OTHER parameters. Not a very typical use-case

Comment: This is a standard use case actually. You omit properties to create a new object, and sometimes use the omitted properties. When developing with React, for example, we use it all the time to prepare the props for children.

Comment: This is dangerous in quite a lot of cases. You have no protection against any other values being added. E.g. if you're filtering sensitive fields out of the result of a database query before returning it as an http response, any new sensitive fields added will remain.